# how to make a method to be static?

Tags: java, c++

In java we can make a method of a class to be `static` by writing the keyword `static` before the type of the method : `public static string some_method() { ... }`

In C++ how to make a method `static` ?

Comment: Just add a colon (`:`) after the `public`.

Comment: I hope you're using [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/10077) to learn C++.

Comment: @pheromix It may not be a bad idea to follow a good C++ book all the way to the end; this question would have been answered in there somewhere.

Comment: Even though I provided an answer below, this question could have been answered with a trivial web search. +1 for reading a good book or going through some other-media tutorial. -- edit: I added [java], as this is about Java-C++-Transition/Transcription.

Comment: Would it be the case that all you need is just a global function which Java dose not have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use the keyword `static` just like in Java.

With your example:

```
public static string some_method() { ... }
```

In C++:

```
public:
    static string some_method() { ... }
```

In this case, the colon (`:`) is the only difference; though in C++, `public:` designates all following functions as `public`, not only the one it is attached to.

However, please take notice that this answer just gives a fish, instead of teaching to fish. Depending on what you want to achieve, there are plenty alternatives in C++ to achieve something in a sane, idiomatic way.